# How do I use Platform Builder 5.0 on Windows7(x86)

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I want to use `Platform Builder 5.0` on a PC running `Windows 7 (x86)` O/S. I don't have to taggle any 64 bit issue, since the PC is not capable to run a 64 bit version.

Is this somehow possible to tweak the installation? I would prefer not to use the Windows XP mode because the use of a Virtual PC is slow and usually give additional problems.

Harper

Comment: I did not try to do this. Did you? What type of problems do you encounter?

Comment: Problems in the Win7-environment: (1) Program claims that it is not compatible at start (2) SYSGEN never completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform Builder 5.0 is really incompatible with Windows 7. It's only possible in a XP virtual machine.